# How to correctly display in a PDF table of contents a reference to a theorem-like object?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, cross-referencing

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\begin{document}
    \section{one}
    
    \begin{theorem}
        \label{thm:one}
        This is a theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \section{Proof of \Cref{thm:one}}
    
\end{document}
```

The output is the obvious one and the section title "Proof of Theorem 1" is correctly displayed in the TOC, but not in the TOC of a PDF reader, where instead "Proof of \Cref{thm:one}" is displayed. Is there an easy fix for this issue?

Comment: `\section{Proof of \texorpdfstring{\Cref{thm:one}}{Theorem~\protect\ref{thm:one}}}` could work but it is not enough automated... If, anyway, it fits your needs or not just let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This works well enough that I'll just implement it by hand for the few instances where I need it. Would you mind copying it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is the usual way:

```
\section{Proof of \texorpdfstring{\Cref{thm:one}}{Theorem~\protect\ref{thm:one}}}
```